# MVC Filter Database with IIdentity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, repository-pattern

In my MVC Site a Teacher login and should view his classes and all books used in his classes.

The teacher should not be able to see someone else class or book.

Here's my model

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Books
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Title {get; set;}

    public int CourseId {get; set;}
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int Name {get; set;}

    public int TeacherId {get; set;}
}
```

I use a RepositoryPattern with UnitOfWork.

In order to get all classes tobe showned I should put in my Controller this kind of line :

```
var classes = classRepository.All.Where(x => x.TeacherId == currentTeacher.Id)
```

Things will get worst with the BookControler since I need to check all classes of the currentTeacher:

```
var classes = classRepository.All.Where(x => x.TeacherId == currentTeacher.Id)
var books = bookRepository.All.Where(x => classes.Contains(y => y.Id == x.CourseId)
```

It seems to me that this kind of approach may lead to some functional bug. 
what I would like to do is that when a teacher login my repositories  auto-filter in order to keep only datas concerning the currentTeacher, therefore in my controller I would have :

```
var classes = classRepository.All; // Already filtered on currentTeacher
```

or

```
var books = bookRepository.All; // Already filtered on currentTeacher
```

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `All(IPrincipal user)` method in which you pass in the current authenticated user. This `All` method will lookup the `Identity.Name` value in your object context's Teacher collection to get the ID which is then returned.

i.e. `.Where(x => x.TeacherId == currentTeacher.Id)` is the return value from this new `All` method.

Comment: Sorry... I meant the Book repository which needs to check into the classRepository. In thiscase IIdentity is not enough.

My real question is : is there a way to filter a Database by fltering on the teachers? Basically the filtered database will contains only datas related to a specific teacher.

Comment: Yes you'll be able to do it that way. If you can find `currentTeacher.Id` from the IPrincipal object, you can filter based on this.